# Socket inputStream read message giving an unexpected length

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have a function that reads a message from the client with a timeout of 100ms. In my code, I use this function in a loop until I get a string that is different than "" and that is how I know I got the message I needed and can continue my code. For some reason, it works for the first socket, but when I send what I received from socket to socket 2 and wait for socket2 to respond, I get bytesReceived = -1 even though socket2 is still connected and alive.

Code:

```java
public String getMessage(int socketNumber) {
    Socket socket = socket1;
    if(socketNumber == 2){
        socket = socket2;
    }
    byte[] message = new byte[4096];
    int bytesReceived = 0;

    try {
        socket.setSoTimeout(100);
        bytesReceived = socket.getInputStream().read(message);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        return "";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    System.out.println("AMOUNT OF BYTES RECEIVED FROM" + socketNumber + " IS " + bytesReceived);
    // Convert the message to a string.
    return new String(message, 0, bytesReceived);
}
```

Comment: "I get bytesReceived = -1 even though `socket2` is still connected and alive": No. The socket is connected, but the connection is closed. The peer has closed the connection. The connection is no longer alive. This condition is inevitable at some point, unless you get a connection reset, and your code need to test for it. It's not an 'unexpected length' at all.

Answer (score -1):

If a message is passed that is larger than your byte array, your code will not receive the whole message. Also, you might be better to wrap the `InputStream` in a `Reader` since some characters are two bytes and might be chopped in half between two `read` operations.

You could try something like:

```java
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), charset);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    builder.append(buffer, 0, count);
}
return builder.toString();
```

Comment: Yeah, but the message I send is really small - it looks something like this:
Name#x1#y1#x2#y2

0 <= x1 <= 7
0 <= y1 <= 7
0 <= x2<= 7
0 <= y2<= 7

What  I don't understand is why I get bytesReceived = -1 and not the actual message from socket2 or just a SocketTimeoutException if the stream between socket2 and the server is still open and active

Comment: @Demo The only reason you'd get -1 if the stream is closed (end of stream is reached). You really need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Should do this why? Mere code is not an answer. You have to explain.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, so basically this is a server for my Chess game, and I used a similar function to this in my other class that only has one socket in a while loop that uses a read message and gets a timeout if no message was received. I can provide that class in addition to the class where I had my original issue and that way you can explain why it works correctly for that class but not for the class where the issue was found.

Comment: @Demo He *has* explained it, and so have I. The peer has closed the connection.

Comment: @lance-java Your new explanatory text doesn’t explain the -1. Read the question.

Comment: Using a socket timeout is NOT a good way to detect the end of a message. Especially such a low timeout as 100ms. Network latency can easily delay bytes more than that time. You **should** be sending the message's byte/char length before then sending the message itself, that way you can read the length first and then read however many bytes/chars the length says.

Comment: Your edits continue to ignore every point that has been raised.

Comment: I know my solution doesn't solve the `bytesReceived = -1` issue but it does address issues with the code provided

Comment: So it isn't a solution, so it isn't an answer.